# How to get more than 50 Lectures of a category from Youtube Education API?

Tags: rest, youtube, youtube-api

I was looking at Youtube Education API V2 and tried to get Lecture feeds of few Categories.But, the maximum I was able to get was 50. Am I doing some thing wrong?

[feed request 1](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?alt=json&category=407&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount&start-index=51&v=2)

[feed request 2](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?alt=json&category=340&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount&start-index=51&v=2)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_education#Lectures  is the API Reference I followed

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be working as intended. There are only 50 entries in those feeds.

If you query https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?category=340&v=2 you'll see `<openSearch:totalResults>50</openSearch:totalResults>` in the response indicating the feed size.

Comment: That means, youtube restrict the number of maximum feedback I could get to 50? I counted the lectures in YOutube's Education page for that particular category and found more that 120 lectures there.